# Allow complex sudo command on Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, sudo

I need to allow a specific command on a Debian Linux box for a single user. I've tried this in the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
# User privilege specification
zabbix  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get --print-uris -qq -y upgrade 2>/dev/null |awk '{print $2}' | wc | awk '{print $1}'
```

This does not work as expected. If I run the command as user zabbix with sudo, it asks for the password (although I have specified the `NOPASSWD` option).

However, this works:

```
# User privilege specification
zabbix  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

But has the drawback that all subcommands of `apt-get` are allowd. Is there a way how I can fix this to only allow a specific command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I disagree with lain.
Although it will work, You do not need `awk` to run as root.
I would not be comfortable with this because you might be able to attack `awk` in some way. It is a full programming language interpreter after all.

When one runs `sudo /usr/bin/apt-get --print-uris -qq -y upgrade 2>/dev/null |awk '{print $2}' | wc | awk '{print $1}'`, They are actually running `sudo /usr/bin/apt-get --print-uris -qq -y upgrade` and then piping/redirecting as the calling user.

Try this: `zabbix  ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get --print-uris -qq -y upgrade`

By the way, there is nothing wrong with putting this in a script as lain does and you could still do that. I would just avoid running awk as root if possible.

Comment: You're correct but if the script is insecure then it doesn't matter what's in it, it can be overwritten and the world is your oyster. If the script is secure then what's in it is secure too.

Answer (score 25):

You are probably falling foul of the way that redirection interacts with sudo. The redirection is performed at the calling user not the privileged user. It would probably be easier for you to wrap you command in a script and to then allow the zabbix user to run that script e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/apt-get --print-uris -qq -y upgrade 2>/dev/null |awk '{print $2}' | wc | awk '{print $1}'
```

the set sudoers as

```
zabbix  ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

Now the whole script will be run as the privileged user and not just the particular apt-get command. Do though ensure that the zabbix user cannot write to the script.

Comment: Someone can probably correct me if sudo already takes care of it (I seem to recall having issues with env variables not being passed), but I'd suggest making awk and wc have their fullpaths as a general best practice for scripts so a user can't do export PATH=~user/bin:$PATH and stick whatever commands the want in a script called awk (or wc) in ~user/bin

Comment: @Foon: I think you're confusing sudo with cron.

Comment: Not confusing it, but http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables does indicate that sudo prevents PATH manipulation (and LD_LIBARRAY_PATH by default)

Comment: I did something similar only I suid'd the evoking script & made it writable only by root. Test if it works for the user with permissions 711, then they can't even see what it's doing to try and circumvent it.